# Prevent celery from running my Django app threads

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have a Django app and I am using celery (with redis) for running processing tasks in the background. In addition, I have a python thread which runs some periodic checks as part of my Django app. Surprisingly, when I am starting celery I see my thread is also running as part of celery. I would like to prevent this behavior and have only one instance of my thread and have it as part of my Django app. How can I prevent it from running in celery?

I tested it on a newly created app and see the exact same behavior:

`settings.py:`

```
...
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
```

`__init__.py:`

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)

def mythread():
    while True:
      print("thread is running")
      sleep(10)

new_thread = Thread(target=mythread, daemon=True)
new_thread.start()
```

`celery.py:`

```
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myapp.settings')

app = Celery('myapp')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Celery output:

```
...
[2022-06-15 16:21:49,923: INFO/MainProcess] Events of group {task} enabled by remote.
[2022-06-15 16:21:49,958: WARNING/MainProcess] thread is running
[2022-06-15 16:21:59,968: WARNING/MainProcess] thread is running
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this workaround in order to prevent the thread from running under celery:

```
app_name = sys.argv[0]
if (app_name.find("celery") == -1):
  new_thread = Thread(target=mythread, daemon=True)
  new_thread.start()
```

If there is a cleaner solution, I will be happy to adopt it.

Comment: Did you find a better solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find a better solution.